# Elasticsearch cluster managed by terraform with eck operator. Version upgrade fails

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, terraform

Our current Production Elasticsearch cluster for logs collection is manually managed and runs on AWS.
I'm creating the same cluster using ECK deployed with Helm under Terraform.
I was able to get all the features replicated (S3 repo for snapshots, ingest pipelines, index templates, etc) and deployed, so, first deployment is perfectly working.
But when I tried to update the cluster (changing the ES version from 8.3.2 to 8.5.2) I get this error:

```
│ Error: Provider produced inconsistent result after apply
│
│ When applying changes to kubernetes_manifest.elasticsearch_deploy, provider "provider\["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubernetes"\]" produced an unexpected new
│ value: .object: wrong final value type: attribute "spec": attribute "nodeSets": tuple required.
│
│ This is a bug in the provider, which should be reported in the provider's own issue tracker.
```

I stripped down my elasticsearch and kibana manifests to try to isolate the problem.
Again, I previously deployed the eck operator with its helm chart: it works, because the first deployment of the cluster is flawless.

I have in my main.tf:

```
resource "kubernetes_manifest" "elasticsearch_deploy" {
  field_manager {
    force_conflicts = true
  }
  computed_fields = \["metadata.labels", "metadata.annotations", "spec.finalizers", "spec.nodeSets", "status"\]
  manifest = yamldecode(templatefile("config/elasticsearch.yaml", {
    version                    = var.elastic_stack_version
    nodes                      = var.logging_elasticsearch_nodes_count
    cluster_name               = local.cluster_name
  }))
}
```

```
resource "kubernetes_manifest" "kibana_deploy" {
  field_manager {
    force_conflicts = true
  }
  depends_on      = \[kubernetes_manifest.elasticsearch_deploy\]
  computed_fields = \["metadata.labels", "metadata.annotations", "spec.finalizers", "spec.nodeSets", "status"\]
  manifest = yamldecode(templatefile("config/kibana.yaml", {
    version                    = var.elastic_stack_version
    cluster_name               = local.cluster_name
    namespace                  = local.stack_namespace
  }))
}
```

and my manifests are:

```
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  annotations:
    eck.k8s.elastic.co/downward-node-labels: "topology.kubernetes.io/zone"
  name: ${cluster_name}
  namespace: ${namespace}
spec:
  version: ${version}
  volumeClaimDeletePolicy: DeleteOnScaledownAndClusterDeletion
  monitoring:
    metrics:
      elasticsearchRefs:
      - name: ${cluster_name}
    logs:
      elasticsearchRefs:
      - name: ${cluster_name}
  nodeSets:
    - name: logging-nodes
    count: ${nodes}
    config:
      node.store.allow_mmap: false]]
```

```
apiVersion: kibana.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Kibana
metadata:
  name: ${cluster_name}
  namespace: ${namespace}
spec:
  version: ${version}
  count: 1
  elasticsearchRef:
    name: ${cluster_name}
  monitoring:
    metrics:
      elasticsearchRefs:
        - name: ${cluster_name}
    logs:
      elasticsearchRefs:
        - name: ${cluster_name}
  podTemplate:
    metadata:
      labels:
        stack_name: ${stack_name}
        stack_repository: ${stack_repository}
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: ${service_account}
      containers:
        - name: kibana
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 1Gi
              cpu: "1"
```

When I change the version, testing a cluster upgrade (e.g. going from 8.3.2 to 8.5.2), I get the error mentioned at the beginning of this post.
Is it a eck operator bug or I'm doing something wrong?
Do I need to add some other entity in the 'computed_fields' and remove 'force_conflicts'?

Comment: Has the `apiVersion` of the Elasticsearch changed maybe between K8s versions?

Answer (score 1):

In the end, a colleague of mine found that indeed you have to add the whole "spec" to the computed_fields, like this:

```
resource "kubernetes_manifest" "elasticsearch_deploy" {
  field_manager {
    force_conflicts = true
  }
  computed_fields = ["metadata.labels", "metadata.annotations", "spec", "status"]
  manifest = yamldecode(templatefile("config/elasticsearch.yaml", {
    version                    = var.elastic_stack_version
    nodes                      = var.logging_elasticsearch_nodes_count
    cluster_name               = local.cluster_name
  }))
}
```

This way I got a proper cluster upgrade, without full cluster restart.

Underlying reason: the eck operator makes changes to the spec section. Even if you just do a terraform apply without any changes (and "spec" is not added to the computed_fields), terraform will find that something has changed and will perform an update.

Answer (score 0):

Its nice that you already have a working solution. Just out of curiousness, why do you use `kubernetes_manifest` instead of `helm_release` api from terraform to upgrade your es cluster? We upgraded from 8.3.2 to 8.5.2 using helm_release and everything went smooth.

Comment: Because we decided to follow the eck operator route:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59165837/elasticsearch-on-kubernetes-elastic-cloud-eck-vs-helm-charts